# "Comme prévu", "comme convenu", "comme promis", "comme demandé", "comme (déjà) évoqué", "comme démontré (précédemment)", etc

Tags: expressions, usage, registre

Mon Dictionnaire des difficultés de la langue française dit : *comme prévu, comme convenu et autres expressions elliptiques de ce genre, sont du langage familier ou commercial*.
C'est un ouvrage rédigé par Adolphe Thomas, Chef correcteur des dictionnaires Larousse. Le lemme ne donne pas plus de précisions. Vu que c'est un vieil ouvrage (1<sup>re</sup> édition 1971; 2<sup>de</sup> 1988), je pose ici quelques questions.

1. Quand peut-on utiliser de telles expressions elliptiques ?
2. Sont-elles acceptables ?   Sont-elles considérées du langage familier ?
3. Sont-elles considérées comme des anglicismes ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La construction *comme + participe passé* présente une ellipse du sujet et de l'auxiliaire. *Comme* introduit dans ce cas une comparaison et est synonyme de *ainsi que*.

Pour moi il ne s'agit pas de langage familier, Grevisse signale simplement ce cas dans le chapitre sur les ellipses du verbe, sans dire qu'il s'agirait de langage familier. Et ce n'est en aucun cas un anglicisme. Bien entendu, il s'agit d'une ellipse et il n'est pas interdit d'écrire la proposition subordonnée en entier, mais le fait de faire une ellipse n'est pas en soi familier, même si on considère que développer la construction peut relever d'un langage plus soutenu.

- Je viendrai te voir dimanche prochain, comme prévu. (normal)
- Je viendrai te voir dimanche prochain, comme nous l'avions prévu/comme c'était prévu (un peu lourd pour moi, à l'oral comme à l'écrit)
- Nous passerons faire la réparation jeudi prochain, comme convenu. (normal)
- Nous passerons faire la réparation jeudi prochain, comme nous en avions convenu. (un peu solennel)

*Comme démontré précédemment* ne relève pas pour moi du langage familier, car pour le dire il faut avoir déjà fait une démonstration, chose qu'on ne fait que dans des circonstances spécifiques et rarement dans un contexte familier (pour me référer [au commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/39700/comme-pr%C3%A9vu-comme-convenu-comme-promis-comme-demand%C3%A9-comme-d%C3%A9j%C3%A0-%C3%A9#comment79158_39700)), encore moins dans un contexte commercial.

Ce qui, par contre, me semble relever du langage familier – et parfois employé dans des documents commerciaux – c'est l'emploi de « comme entendu » à la place de « comme convenu » :

> La météo a freiné l'avancement des empierrements mais les travaux s'arrêteront fin septembre, comme entendu avec les chasseurs de palombes. (*La Dépêche du Midi*, [26/08/2017](https://www.ladepeche.fr/article/2017/08/26/2633692-les-travaux-de-la-route-forestiere-avancent.html)).

Ce que je trouve familier ici c'est l'emploi du verbe *entendre* dans ce sens là. Le verbe étant « s'entendre » (pronominal et qui veut dire « se mettre d'accord »), en faisant l'ellipse on perd la pronominalité<sup>1</sup>.

À ne pas confondre avec « comme de bien entendu », expression très familière<sup>2</sup> qui veut dire *évidemment* et rendue très populaire par la [chanson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yEQbggBoz-I) de ce nom interprétée par Arletty et Michel Simon dans le film *[Circonstances atténuantes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circonstances_att%C3%A9nuantes_(film,_1939))*.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Et donc dans l'exemple cité je dirais « comme l'entreprise s'en était entendu avec les chasseurs ».

<sup>2</sup> Qui résulte de la contamination ([TLF A.1.b)](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/contamination)) de *comme de juste* et de *bien entendu*.</sub>

Comment: Le langage permet de faire passer des choses dans un discours : cela tombe sous le sens que la seconde formulation est incorrecte.

Comment: Les deux phrases n'ont pas la même valeur sémantique.

Answer (score 1):

> Le grand classique des dictionnaires de difficultés qui permet de déjouer tous les pièges d'orthographe, de grammaire et de conjugaison. **Chaque mot est étudié sous l'angle de la difficulté qu'il présente** ; de très nombreux exemples ; des tableaux récapitulatifs sur des points particuliers (mots composés, formes invariables...).

On peut supposer qu'il faut lire le texte. La question relève à mon sens d'un emploi qui dépend de la perspective adoptée ou du registre adapté par rapport au contexte. On ne peut pas en ajouter plus puisque aucune expression n'est fournie.